# Best way to ensure a PouchDB/CouchDB replication succeeded?

Tags: database, couchdb, pouchdb

My app is going to do some basic DB replications from a remote CouchDB to a local PouchDB, using the [PouchDB.replicate()](https://pouchdb.com/api.html#replication) method. There's multiple "master" couch dbs, which should be small and change infrequently, which users can choose to download locally. Despite ample searching I'm not 100% clear on the standard practice of how to do this reliably if my app explodes in the middle of a replication.

My understanding is that pouch and couch use checkpoints, such that if you call PouchDB.replicate() again after the app crashes or browser window closes or whatever, it will pick up from the same point. But looking through the pouchDB docs, I don't see a clear way to tell if a previous replication failed. The DB seq number between the source/target DBs isn't guaranteed to match, I doubt any 'complete' or 'error' events will fire if the app crashes, and db.info() doesn't seem to have anything.

I can think of a few potential approaches:

1. Create a locally-stored "replication-completed" field for each db which is set to false when a replication starts, and set to true when you get a 'complete' event.
2. Set replication options "live" and "retry" to true. However AFAIK these still wouldn't automatically continue an in-progress replication if the app crashed, and I don't really want live replications, and you can't have "retry" without "live" also being true.
3. Just call PouchDB.replicate() for every db every time my app launches. This ensures everything's up-to-date, but I sacrifice control over when db updates are checked/pulled.
4. Use [this](https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/pull/6812) supposed 'pending' property of the info object from `replication.on('change', function(info) { //check whether there's pending changes })`. However this isn't even in the documentation.

Couch (but not pouch) has a [Replicator database](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/replication/replicator.html) that solves this, but I think that could only be used for pouch-->couch replications. I saw a pouch plugin for it but it seemed badly outdated.

Any suggestions? I feel like I'm missing something obvious here.

Comment: [PouchDB documentation](https://pouchdb.com/api.html#replication) clearly points out the `complete` event when performing replication.  The `complete` event is fired when the source and target db's are in sync or if replication was cancelled.

Comment: @RamblinRose aye, I'd listen for that in most cases. But the question is, what do I do if the app crashes? Upon app launch I'd like to check if there were any previous replications that failed.

Comment: If your app crashes unexpectedly, you need to address that reason and not hope that other subsystems are resilient to faulty code. Fix the problem code instead of dancing around it. Seriously.

Comment: Also FWIW replication will pick up where it last left off.  You clearly have bigger problems than replication.

Comment: @RamblinRose I'm not actually getting crashes, but this is a mobile app, it WILL happen. Users will manually close the app, they will run out of battery, Ionic or some library will bug out, etc. Accounting for possible errors is just good practice.
And yeah, I know it will pick back up if I manually re-run it thanks to checkpoints. Replicating every db on app startup is one of the potential solutions I mentioned.

Comment: I get it. Maybe using a [local document](https://pouchdb.com/guides/local-documents.html) to maintain replication state would be a good course. For finer control a network up check could drive control of replication, with progress logged to the local document via replication events. Also see this [SO Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26892438/how-to-know-when-weve-lost-sync-with-a-remote-couchdb)

Comment: Thanks. Well the advice I got on the pouchDB slack was to just re-run the replications, which works fine for my use case. Perhaps if someone has more or larger or more frequently-updating dbs where replicating everything is a bigger deal, they'd be interested in an alternate solution. Gonna leave this open in case someone comes by with an ezpz silver bullet.

Comment: Silver bullets are always welcome 